# insert aspect in between of method execution

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspect

As we know that in AOP, we can introduce aspects using `@Before`
`@After` and `@AfterReturning`.
But if i want to insert any Logger statement in between of method, i.e. after execution and before the end of the method. How can we do this using Spring AOP?

Comment: What is the difference between "after execution and before the end of the method" and @After?

Comment: Your description is unclear. Please update the question with some sample code and explain what should happen when. And please also answer the  question asked by @Heri.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot put AOP in between your method execution. You can do before, after, around, etc.

If you want in between I would suggest refactor your method into multiple methods and use AOP to the relevant method.